# Use update_columns on an hstore attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

Is there an equivalent of `update_columns` for `hstore` attributes in rails 4?

My model is:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :additions, :small, :medium, :big, :image_version
end
```

Assuming I want to update `small`.
I tried:

```
@image = Image.first
@image.update_columns(small: 'my_small_image')
```

But I receive, of course:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "small" of relation "contents" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "images" SET "small" = 'my_small_image' WHERE "imag...
                              ^
: UPDATE "images" SET "small" = 'my_small_image' WHERE "images"."id" = 1
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

EDIT: I can't use `update_attributes`, because I need to save **only** the passed arguments.

`update_attributes` calls `save`, and I don't want this, because it saves all other changed attributes, not only the one passed.

Example:

```
@image = Image.first
@image.big = 'fjdiosjfoa'
@image.update_attributes(small: 'my_small_image')
```

Both big and small are saved.

Instead, with `update_columns`, only small get saved. How to do it with an hstore?

Answer (score 3):

Use update_column but pass in the hstore attribute and a hash. To prevent any existing hstore values getting blown away, you need to merge the existing values:

```
@image.update_column(:additions, @image.additions.merge({ 'small' => 'my_small_image' }) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `update_attributes(small: 'my_small_image')` if you want to save.

Use `assign_attributes(small: 'my_small_image')` if you dont want to save.

Comment: Mhh I need to use `update_columns` and not `update_attributes`, because the second calls `save`. I'm adding some details in my question.

Comment: `assign_attributes` does not help you?

Comment: no... It's a bit difficult to explain. Take a look to the example in my question.